# Obtaining cdf from pdf when pdf is defined on limited region/support

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, pareto-distribution

This is a very simple question, but I want to make sure I am doing it correctly.

I have the pdf from a Pareto distribution:

$$f(x) = 160 x^{-6}, \ \ 2 \leq x < \infty$$

and want to obtain the cdf

$$F(x) = \int_{- \infty}^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t$$

In this case, is it the same if I substitue the lower bound of the integral to $2$ since the pdf is specifically defined for $x \in [2, \infty)$ such that $F(x) = -32x^{-5} + 1$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: The confusion only arises because you failed to define what $f$ was to the left of $2$. If you correct the omission, the difficulty immediately disappears.

Comment: I have seen the problems defined this way almost all of the time. I was unsure if it always was implied that everything outside this interval was $0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's write the calculus formally.

$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      160x^{-6} & x\ge2\\
      0 & x< 2 
   \end{cases}
$$

To get from $f(x)$ to $F(x)$, integrate:

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt.$$

But we can break up the integral into an integral from $-\infty$ to $2$ and another from $2$ to $x$.

$$ F(x) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) \ dt = \int \limits_{-\infty}^2 0 \ dt + \int \limits_2^{x} 160t^{-6} \ dt = \int \limits_2^{x} 160t^{-6} \ dt.$$

Comment: For the answer to be completely accurate, you need to specify $x\ge 2.$  Obviously $F(x)=0$ for all $x \lt 2,$ but that differs from what your formula asserts.